# maked the default checked radio do the js function?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Hi guys I have been coding a script for storing emails and when i made the edit page i wanted

some radios to be checked by default and this radios have an onfoucse which executes a

javascript function I was able to get the radios checked but the js didn't work here is a

**sample :**

```
echo"<input type='radio' name='step1' value='ftime' onfouces='rollit('ftime');'".radiocheck('ftime',$check['step1'])." />";
```

I made the radiocheck function to check if the radio should be selected.

the main problem is to make the js function work

the js function:

```
function rrolldate(myname) {
    var year = "<select name=" + myname + "5-2 size='1'> \
<option value='13'>2013</option> \
<option value='14'>2014</option> \
<option value='15'>2015</option> \
<option value='16'>2016</option> \
<option value='17'>2017</option> \
<option value='18'>2018</option> \
<option value='19'>2019</option> \
<option value='20'>2020</option> \
<option value='21'>2021</option> \
<option value='22'>2022</option> \
<option value='23'>2023</option> \
<option value='24'>2024</option> \
</select>";

    str1 = "rrolldate1('daily');";
    str2 = "rrolldate2('weekly');";
    str3 = "rrolldate3('monthly');";
    str4 = "rrolldate4('yearly');";
    var recurring = "Daily<input type='radio' name='step2' value='daily' onclick=" + str1 + " />    \
               Weekly<input type='radio' name='step2' value='weekly' onclick=" + str2 + " /> \
               Monthly<input type='radio' name='step2' value='monthly' onclick=" + str3 + " /> \
               Yearly<input type='radio' name='step2' value='yearly' onclick=" + str4 + " /> \
               <p id='step3'></p>";
    document.getElementById("step2").innerHTML = "Start Date: " + year + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + setname(myname, '1') + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + setname(myname, '2') + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + setname(myname, '3') + "<br /><br />" + recurring;
}
```

Comment: is onfouces a typo , as it should be onfocus

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript function. And also, why use radio buttons instead of checkboxes?

Comment: the on onfouces is a typo and i have add the javascript funtion

Comment: There is no `checked` event on the javascript side if you mark the button as checked by php (so hard coded in the html markup you generate).

Comment: Are you calling where are functions `rrolldate1` - `rolldate4`?

Comment: you can use `onchange` event instead of `focus` and use `.prop` function to set check uncheck from javascript

Comment: yes i calling them so they can also do there job

Comment: what you want to do, please comment with what exactly you want. Your question is not clear

Comment: vikas devde when this radio is checked it will output a list and some radios this radios are already stored in the database by the user and when he wants to edit i want him to see his old selected options

Comment: you mean  when your page loads some of the radio buttons to be shown as checked?

Comment: yes i got the buttons checked but the js didn't work

Comment: Do you want to set radio button as check or unchecked from javascript?

Comment: you can see an example here http://www.sendrecurring.com sing up make an email a see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still couldn't get what you want but I am writing this to clear some points..

if you want your radio button to be checked after load just add a `checked` attribute

```
<input type="radio" checked>
```

the above will be a checked radio button

if you want to set the radio checked from js then you can use `.prop` function(If you are using jQuery)

```
$(your_radio_button_selector).prop('checked', true);
```

or to set unchecked

```
$(your_radio_button_selector).prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: the checked thing didn't work but what I'm really trying to do is to make a clone of this site http://www.sendrecurring.com but my problem is with the edit section after you sign up and make an email and try to edit it, it will show you the options that you selected i couldn't make that happen on my script

Comment: You have to provide all your code to get your answer. Be as much clear as you can

Comment: the `checked` attribute will work at the load time only,

Comment: can you get with me on skype and i can show you?

Comment: instead you can make a jsfiddle to reproduce your problem, then come and comment here with your fiddle link.

Comment: i can't show the php on jsfiddle

Comment: your question is about javascript, you are talking about javascript function, so put only javascript code

Comment: my script has php html js i have put that in the tags

Comment: i can show you a live demo of my script?

Comment: http://111.118.185.91/~darkness/mail-1/mail.php

Comment: when I click on radio button another set of radio buttons or checkboxes are shown, which you are adding from javascript, do you want some of them to be checked?

Comment: yes i do it's what i want

Comment: so thats what my answer says buddy use jQuery in your project, and call `.prop` function on radio button whichever you want to be checked  after you have added them..simple

Comment: checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gz3F3/1/ this might give you some idea